# Deleting a comment in a modern SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, comments, modern

Is it possible to delete a single comment from the comment section at the bottom of the a SharePoint modern page?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use REST API to retrieve comments, and manage comments.

To delete a specific comment from a modern page, make a Delete request to:

```
https://technet.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/_api/web/lists(<list GUID>')/GetItemById(<page item id>)/Comments(<comment id>)
```

Reference:

[Working with the Page Comments REST API](https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/working-with-page-comments-rest-api-in.html)

A script demo of deleting a comment from a modern page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(DeleteComment, "sp.js");  
function DeleteComment() {  
    var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;  
    console.log("from top nav - " + siteURL);  
    var apiPath = siteURL + "/_api/web/lists('F0D56E41-B532-4F0D-A5B2-000FDE46B86F')/GetItemById(26)/Comments(1)";  
    $.ajax({  
        url: apiPath,  
        type: "DELETE",  
        headers: {  
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": "*"
        },  
        async: false,  
        success: function(data) {  
            alert("The comment Deleted successfully");  
        },  
        eror: function(data) {  
            console.log("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
        }  
    });  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @JoannaW_MSFT but where do I inject this JavaScript in a modern page? I didn't think custom JavaScript could be added to a modern SharePoint page?

Comment: You can use the script in the classic page in the same site for running the script. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a no code way as well.
Navigate to the Site Contents / Document Library and select a view that contains document **Name**.
Hover over the document Name until you see the 3 dots and then select Details.

If you scroll down on details then there is is at the bottom. You can view all activity or just comments. And then Delete the ones you wish.

Comments on Comments appear to be removed as well. But at least we can open up Comments to our users and maintain control! :)