# SPO: How to get all modern page comments that @-mention me?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

I need to get a list of @-mentions in page comments for the current user. On the client, so ultimately via JavaScript.

Say there is a modern page and another user at-mentions me like this:
[image]

Is there an API that gives me this specific comment and other comments that mention me? (Iterating all pages and comments is no option.)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the comments in the site page by REST API below. And then you could filter the items by mentioned person by JavaScript.

/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById(1)/Comments

[Working with the Page Comments REST API in SharePoint Communication sites.](https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/working-with-page-comments-rest-api-in.html)

There is a similar post:

[Deleting a comment in a modern SharePoint page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245418/deleting-a-comment-in-a-modern-sharepoint-page)